# How to trace image to grease pencil then covert to mesh with the same faces as used for the grease pencil

Tags: modeling, mesh, grease-pencil

Im looking to take a silhouette image and turn it to a mesh object with the same fill.
When I used trace image to grease pencil then converted to path then converted to mesh. This results in just mesh edges of the original grease pencil which can easily be filled if it dosnt contain internal holes or complex geometry.
Is there a way to keep the grease pencil fill and still covert it to a mesh? Or what is the best way to use the edges to cut holes in the face if its not attached to the face? Orrr can a use the edges to cut out the silhouette on a separate plane?

[image: on the left is trace image to grease pencil, on the right is that grease pencil converted to path then mesh and filled with F in edit mode]